# PHP - Extract Name from a String using Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have some strings in loop like below example.

1) Sold by Olympia Industries Ltd. (4.7 out of 5 | 33,445 ratings) and Fulfilled by Amazon. Gift-wrap available.

2) Sold by Health first trading (4.3 out of 5 | 47 ratings) and Fulfilled by Amazon. Gift-wrap available.

3) Sold and fulfilled by hamsaveni (4.1 out of 5 | 101 ratings).

4) Sold and fulfilled by Coffee Shopee (3.4 out of 5 | 7 ratings).

What i want is to extract the name of seller i.e.

1) Olympia Industries Ltd.
2) Health first trading
3) hamsaveni
4) Coffee Shopee

I know we can do it by matching the first brace "(" and with some if else condition. But unfortunately i am not able to do it.

Any help will really appreciated.

Comment: The regex would be `.+(?=\()`.

Comment: This is impossible in a general manner, since the start of the seller naming is not clearly defined. You first have to specify a rule which allows this.

Comment: @Murat, Thanks for your valuable comment. Unfortunately ".+(?=\()." is not removing the Sold by and Sold and fulfilled by. Is there any way?

Comment: @ShariqueAnwer You can erase it with `String.replace("unwantedString,"")` or whatever the equivalent is in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match('/by([^(]+)/', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks Toto and also Murat. It worked! preg_match('/by([^(]+)/', $seller2, $matches); $seller=str_replace("by ","",$matches[0]);

Answer (score 0):

I consider that seller name is start after "by"  and end before the (. then

it will work for you.

substr($string,strpos($string,'by')+2,strpos($string,'(')-strpos($string,'by')-2);

Answer (score 0):

I hope people don't mind me using .NET regex syntax (it's pretty similar), but here's what I came up with:

```
(?:by)([A-Za-z ]+)(?:\([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)
```

Basically, the name is a captured group consisting of some combination of letters and spaces that occurs after the word "by" (which is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon), since all you actually care about capturing is the name) and a rating (also a non-capturing group).